# C : Insert/get element in/from void array

Tags: c, arrays, generics, void, memcpy

I have to create a generic array that can contain generic data structures.
How can i put a generic structure into an empty slot of my void array?

This is my code.

```
struct CircularBuffer {
    int E;
    int S;
    int length;   // total number of item allowable in the buffer
    int sizeOfType;   // size of each element in the buffer
    void *buffer;
};

struct CircularBuffer* circularBufferInit(int length, int sizeOfType) {

    struct CircularBuffer *cb = malloc(sizeof(struct CircularBuffer));
    cb->E = 0;
    cb->S = 0;
    cb->length = length;
    cb->sizeOfType = sizeOfType;
    cb->buffer = malloc(sizeOfType *length);
    return cb;
}

int circularBufferIsEmpty(struct CircularBuffer* cb) {
    if (cb->S == cb->E)
        return 1; //empty
    else
        return 0;
}

int circularBufferIsFull(struct CircularBuffer *cb) {
    int nE = (cb->E + 1) % (cb->length);
    if (nE == cb->S)
        return 1; //full
    else
        return 0;
}

void circularBufferAdd(struct CircularBuffer *cb, void* obj) {
    memcpy(cb->buffer + cb->E, obj, cb->sizeOfType);
}
[...]
```

memcpy is the problem...

Comment: SO is no tutorial or consulting site. If you ahve a _specific_ problem please provide a [mcve]. First you might want to take the [tour].

Comment: `memcpy((char *)cb->buffer + (cb->E * cb->sizeOfType), obj, cb->sizeOfType);`

Comment: Basically, you can't do pointer arithmetic on `void *`, so you need to cast to `char *`... then multiply the element number by the size to get the right offset in `char`s.

Comment: Shouldn't `circularBufferAdd()` also do something like, `cb->E = (cb->E + 1) % cb->length;`?

Comment: yes, @Dmitri, exactly

Comment: @Dmitri: Note that GCC has an extension, enabled by default, that treats `void *` as if type '`void`' has a size of `1`, like a `char` has a size of `1`.  This can lead to people being confused.  Strict standard compliance disallows arithmetic on void pointers, as you indicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that essentially you're trying to figure out how to offset a `void *` to the address of an array element of known size but unknown type so you can pass it to `memcpy()`.

It looks as though, in `circularBufferAdd()`, `cb->E` gives the index of the element you want to copy to, `cb->buffer` is the `void *` to the array, `obj` is the item to be copied, and `cb->sizeOfType` is the size each array element (and `obj`).  In that case you can change:

```
    memcpy(cb->buffer + cb->E, obj, cb->sizeOfType);
```

to:

```
    memcpy((char *)cb->buffer + (cb->E * cb->sizeOfType), obj, cb->sizeOfType);
```

Since you can't use pointer arithmetic with a `void *`, you'd cast it to `char *`.  Then, you can multiply the element index by the element size to get the offset of the element in bytes, and use that to get the address of the element you need.

Comment: I have tried with your hint:
`struct CircularBuffer* cb = circularBufferInit(20, sizeof(int));
    circularBufferAdd(cb, (void*)6);
    int i;
    i = (int) circularBufferRead(cb);
    printf("%d", i); `

But there is a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Simon That's a different problem... "`(void *)6`" doesn't make sense (it gives a `void *` that points at the memory address `6`, not the address of an integer with the value 6).  You need to give the address of an actual object/variable.  Also, a `circularBufferRead()` function (which you hadn't shown) can't return the object from the array without knowing its type... you'd have to use pointers.

Comment: It's true! My bad! Thank you. So, now: `int a = 6; circularBufferAdd(cb, &a); [...]`.
Now it works fine. Thanks :)
And for `circularBufferRead`, yes...i use a pointer! `void* circularBufferRead(struct CircularBuffer *cb) {
    void* obj = malloc(cb->sizeOfType);
    obj = &cb->buffer[cb->S];
    return obj;
}`. So, i can use it in this way: `int i; i = *(int*) circularBufferRead(cb);`

Comment: Sorry...the last comment is "a lie"!! This is the working code: `memcpy(obj, (char *)cb->buffer + (cb->S * cb->sizeOfType), cb->sizeOfType);`